# SQL Server 2008 + Creating a cross-tab stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, crosstab

I have two tables that I want to join and create a crosstab table in SQL 2008:

**TableA:**

```
 Auto_ID | Fiscal_Period | Amount 
   1     | 01012012      | NULL 
   1     | 01022012      | 80 
   1     | 01032012      | NULL 
   2     | 01012012      | NULL 
   2     | 01022012      | 10
```

**TABLEB:**

```
Auto_ID | Row_ID | StaticData
   1    |    1   | sampledata
   2    |    2   | data1
```

I would like to use cross table to dynamic create the following table structure:

```
Row_ID | StaticData  | FiscalPeriod(01012012) | FiscalPeriod(01022012) | FiscalPeriod(01032012)
   1   | sampledata  | NULL                   | 80                     | NULL
   2   | data1       | NULL                   | 10                     | NULL
```

My current query joins the tables correctly; however, I am having difficulty transposing the fiscal periods into my header row.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 
         B.Row_Id as RowID, B.StaticData as StaticData, A.Fiscal_Period AS FPPD 
      FROM TableA A 
      LEFT JOIN TableB B ON A.Auto_ID = B.Auto_ID)
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! (there's also absolutely no need for tons of `&nbsp;` or `<br/>` elements, that way....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I would do:

First create some test data:

```
CREATE TABLE tblA (Auto_ID INT,Fiscal_Period  VARCHAR(100),Amount FLOAT)
CREATE TABLE tblB (Auto_ID INT,Row_ID INT,StaticData VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO tblA
SELECT 1,'01012012',NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'01022012',80 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'01032012',NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'01012012',NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'01022012',10 

INSERT INTO tblB
SELECT 1,1,'sampledata' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,2,'data1'
```

Then find the unique columns :

```
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX)
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT
    ROW_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY tblA.Fiscal_Period ORDER BY tblA.Fiscal_Period) AS RowNbr,
    tblA.Fiscal_Period
FROM
    tblA AS tblA
)
SELECT
     @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ','+QUOTENAME('FiscalPeriod('+Fiscal_Period+')'),
                 QUOTENAME('FiscalPeriod('+Fiscal_Period+')'))
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    CTE.RowNbr=1
```

Then execute a pivot with dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000)=
N'SELECT
    *
FROM
(
SELECT
    tblB.Row_ID,
    tblb.StaticData,
    ''FiscalPeriod(''+tblA.Fiscal_Period+'')'' AS Name,
    tblA.Amount
FROM
    tblA AS tblA
    JOIN tblB AS tblB
        ON tblA.Auto_ID=tblB.Auto_ID
) AS p
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Amount)
    FOR Name IN ('+@cols+')
) AS Pvt'
EXECUTE(@query)
```

Then in my case I will drop the temp tables:

```
DROP TABLE tblA
DROP TABLE tblB
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: Yeah it is pretty neat and simple to get the unique column. Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify a flavour of database, please mind, that the following is valid only for MySQL!

A cross-tab query is possible only with a very dirty trick, it is only practically feasable in a stored proc.

You start by thinking out some way, to transform a list of fiscal periods into SQL, something like

```
SELECT
  TABLEB.Row_ID,
  TABLEB.staticdata
  ,fp01012012.Amount as fp01012012amount
  ,fp01022012.Amount as fp01022012amount
  ,fp01032012.Amount as fp01032012amount
FROM
  TABLEB
  LEFT JOIN TableA AS fp01012012 ON fp01012012.Auto_ID=TABLEB.Auto_ID AND fp01012012.Fiscal_Period='01012012'
  LEFT JOIN TableA AS fp01022012 ON fp01022012.Auto_ID=TABLEB.Auto_ID AND fp01022012.Fiscal_Period='01022012'
  LEFT JOIN TableA AS fp01032012 ON fp01032012.Auto_ID=TABLEB.Auto_ID AND fp01032012.Fiscal_Period='01032012'
```

Which you now have to build as dynamic SQL - this is feasable only in a stored proc.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `create_fiscal_data`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `create_fiscal_data` ()
BEGIN
      DECLARE dynfields VARCHAR(10000) DEFAULT 'SELECT TABLEB.Row_ID, TABLEB.staticdata';
      DECLARE dynfrom VARCHAR(10000) DEFAULT ' FROM TABLEB';
      DECLARE period VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT '';
      DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
      DECLARE id INT DEFAULT 7;
      DECLARE periods CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT Fiscal_Period FROM TableA;
      DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=1;
      OPEN periods;

      cycleperiods: LOOP
          FETCH periods INTO period;
          IF done=1 THEN LEAVE cycleperiods; END IF;

          SET dynfields=CONCAT(dynfields,',`fp',period,'`.Amount AS `fp',period,'amount`');
          SET dynfrom=CONCAT(dynfrom,' LEFT JOIN TableA AS `fp',period,'` ON `fp',period,'`.Auto_ID=TABLEB.Auto_ID AND `fp',period,'`.Fiscal_Period="',period,'"');

      END LOOP;

      CLOSE periods;

      SELECT @dynsql:=CONCAT(dynfields,dynfrom) INTO dynfields;
      -- Here comes the trick!
      PREPARE dynqry FROM @dynsql;
      EXECUTE dynqry;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The trick is, to build the SQL into the variable @dynsql (`DECLARE`d variables won't work), then prepare and execute it.

Now the query

```
CALL `create_fiscal_data;`
```

Will create the output you need.

Comment: thanks for the reply, ill try to convert this to sql2008. sorry that i did not specify in my question.

Comment: Should be quite straight forward - please post back your results! I also edited the tags on your question to make that clearer.